# Get Value for selected Item in ListPicker Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I my Webserver a i have a method which return a list of properties:

```
public class ListaProfessor
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Curso { get; set; }
    public String Periodo { get; set; }
    public String Semestre { get; set; }
    public String Turno { get; set; }
    public String Data { get; set; }
}
```

And in my windows phone project i have 4 ListPicker's! each list picker has to receive 4 of the props that i created in my webserver.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="CursoLista" Header="Curso" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="CursoLista_SelectionChanged">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Curso}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And in my Cs file:

```
CursoLista.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

as you can see i'm using `Binding Curso` to select just a list of strings from my database,and i succeed.

[image]

Those are my 4 ListPicker,and i want to select just the Name that will be Bind inside of ListPicker,knowing the `e.Result` come with all props,and i just want to select One!

Comment: Doesn't the itempicker expose a selected property n

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17797919/1876572 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261859/selecteditem-must-always-be-set-to-a-valid-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using MVVM approach you can just do something like this:

```
var content = ((ListPickerItem)CursoLista.SelectedItem).Content;
```

Comment: I saw that you opened another question insteed posting progress here. Well, your choice but if my answer lead you into some ideas you can mark my reply as an answer so noone more will bother trying to help you.

Comment: i just have one more question... whem i use Breakpoint in that line code, shows me all thoses properties `public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Curso { get; set; }
    public String Periodo { get; set; }
    public String Semestre { get; set; }
    public String Turno { get; set; }
    public String Data { get; set; }`
and not just i what select!

Comment: You mean that Content of SelectedItem is an object of a ListaProfessor class and you want it to be a one of its property?

Comment: yes, i just want to store into a string what object i selected!